# Why java Scanner is not reading all the lines?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream

Here is my code which just reads the lines from input stream and displays them but to my surprise its not reading all the lines. Its reading only upto second last line.

Here is  my code :-

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    short n = scan.nextShort();
    short m = scan.nextShort();
    byte[][] topics = new byte[n][m];
    for(short i = 0; i < n; i++){
        char[] arr = scan.nextLine().toCharArray();
        display(arr);

    }
}

private static void display(char[] arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
 }
```

The input is given in this format

```
  4 5
 10101
 11100
 11010
 00101
```

My output is this :-

```
 10101
 11100
 11010
```

Its not having the third line. Why?

Comment: @TheLostMind I just copy pasted the output, so you can also see the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `scan.nextLine()` before your for loop, to read the end of the first line (that contains "4 5"). Without it, the first call to `scan.nextLine()` inside the loop returns an empty String.

Comment: Just a blank call to scan.nextLine(). Is n't there a better way to do that. I mean there should be something like skip().

Comment: @TheLostMind No, the last line is not read because the number of iterations is controlled by the first integer read - 4, so the loop reads the end of the first line and then the next 3 lines.

Comment: @JohnDoe You could replace the two calls to `nextShort` which a single call to `nextLine`, and then split the resulting String and extract the integers from it. Then you wouldn't need the extra call to nextLine.

Comment: But then that would be akin to using the Buffered Reader

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first call to `nextLine()` is reading the empty "line" between the end of "5" (read for `m`) and the line break.

Personally, I would either stop using `Scanner` entirely (in favour of `BufferedReader`) - there's a huge number of questions a bit like this, with it not behaving exactly as you'd like - or *only* just `nextLine()`. Either way, basically process a line at a time:

- Read the first line
- Split it on space and parse the two substrings as `n` and `m`
- Read the next `n` lines

Basically, `Scanner` is "token-oriented" whereas your input format is more "line-oriented".

If you *do* want to use `Scanner.nextShort()` you could always read the first line (either with a `BufferedReader` or a `Scanner`) and create a *new* scanner just from that string:

```
String firstLine = ...;
Scanner firstLineScanner = new Scanner(firstLine);
short n = firstLineScanner.nextShort();
short m = firstLineScanner.nextShort();
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate and precise explanation. So you are suggesting that in problems like these where we have to read from input stream we should prefer BufferedReader over Scanner.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Well I generally prefer `BufferedReader`, as it has a less confusing API.